# How erlang control the process which created by os:cmd?

Tags: erlang

```
1> os:cmd("ping google.com").
```

When above code was executed, there are two process are created, one is erlang process and one is system level process.

**Is there any lib for erlang that we can monitor the system level process** `"ping google.com"`?

Comment: what exactly do you want to do? `os:cmd/1` opens up a port and executes the command you supply. It then blocks and waits for data to be written to the port. On the other end, the port is connected to stdout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [erlexec](https://github.com/saleyn/erlexec) application to run OS processes gives you a lot more control over
those processes. You can send signals to processes (e.g. to stop it), setup Erlang monitors for OS processes and you get the status code when the OS process terminates (`os:cmd` doesn't give you that).

Take a look at the [erlexec documentation](http://saleyn.github.io/erlexec/).